# Save array to base workspace from simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm using a MATLAB function block within a Simulink model. I build this model and run it on a dspace system with 1 kHz. To evaluate my experiment I need the data (20x20 double array) that is calculated in my MATLAB function block. Is it possible to export the data to the base workspace?

Comment: Do you want to export it while simulating the model on your system or while running it on your dSPACE hardware?

Comment: while running it on my dSPACE hardware

Answer (score 0):

To read a variable from your system, the easiest way to do so is using ControlDesk. Create a project and download/start your experiment using ControlDesk, then it is automatically aware of the running application and can read the variable. You now have to configure a Measurement (or Capture in old versions) and export the results to MAT. You can find detailed instructions in the documentation from dSPACE, called HelpDesk.

Alternatively you can use the XIL-API or HIL-API to automate the above steps.